# How to get selected columns in slickgrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am using mleibman/SlickGrid and have checkbox (isChecked) column,

```
var columns = [                
            { id: "tagID", name: "#", field: "tagID", behavior: "select", cssClass: "cell-selection", width: 40, cannotTriggerInsert: true, resizable: false, selectable: false, excludeFromColumnPicker: true },
            { id: "isChecked", name: "isChecked", field: "isChecked", width: 80, minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 80, cssClass: "slick-cell-check", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkbox, editor: Slick.Editors.Checkbox, sortable: true },
            { id: "tagName", name: "tagName", field: "tagName", width: 90, minWidth: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", sortable: true },
            { id: "description", name: "description", field: "description", width: 120, minWidth: 120, cssClass: "cell-title", sortable: true }
        ];
```

How to get all selected/checked rows.
My Approach:

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
    var checkedRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.getDataLength(); i++) {
       if (grid.getDataItem(i).isChecked)
            checkedRows.push(grid.getDataItem(i));
    }
    console.log(checkedRows);                
 }
```

Calling GetCheckedRows never returns first checked row, second checked row comes and deselecting doesn't removes from  checkedRows.

Answer (score 0):

For a start use [6pac SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid), the MLeibman repo is dead now.

Are you missing a closing ')' in the line

```
if (grid.getDataItem(i).isChecked
```

or is this just a typo in what you've posted?

Comment: it was a typo, corrected that. was working on a legacy web app using MLeibman/slickgrid. I am trying 6pac slickgrid now and I can see there is a plugin for checkbox operations. Will update if that workout.